# Why is `sudo npm uninstall htmlhint -g` not removing `htmlhint` folder from `node_modules`? Not working?

Tags: node.js, npm, jshint

I installed `node` and `npm`. I then installed `htmlhint` globally using `sudo npm install htmlint -g`. However, now when I try `sudo npm uninstall htmlhint -g`, I can still see the folder `htmlhint` in `usr/local/lib/node_modules`! Then when I try to re-execute the uninstall command I get the following two messages in the terminal:

- `htmlhint node_modules/htmlhint`
- `jshint node_modules/htmlhint/node_modules/jshint`

What's going on? Why can't I uninstall the modules? Do I really have to go in and manually remove the folders? Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to **cleaning the cache** with **-f** options

Comment: @ChickenSoups umm... are you talking about npm cache clean?